# javascript - How to reduce extra white spaces except line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace, str-replace

`replace(/\s+/g,' ');` reduces all whitespace to one space, including breaks. Sometime I have more than 1 spaces what I want to reduce to one, keeping the new lines, breaks.

Comment: I dont know what are tabs, in this text fields are only that kind of breaks, when you hit the enter key.

Comment: I see you used \s in your regex. `\s` is a whitespace character and represents `[\ \t\r\n\f]`, none of which you can see, and of which, space is only one of a possible 5 in the class. Tab being another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
string = string.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');
```

- `\s` matches all white-spaces including newlines.

OR using lookahead:

```
string = string.replace(/ +(?= )/g, '');
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Thanks for the edit. I should have used `/ +(?= )/`

Comment: My own preference is for lookahead based regex but I believe both will behave same.